# php search url source code for specific word and then redirect to url

Tags: php, redirect

I need the php code for searching the source code of an url for a specific word and if the word exists it will redirect to that url. I have the following code but i don't know how to do the redirect part:

```
<?php
$ch =  curl_init("http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo (stristr ($result, 'specificword')) ? "<div style='text-align:center; color:green'>Online</div>" : "<div style='text-align:center; color:red'>Offline</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: with the code you provided, this is my fix:

```
<?php
    $URL = 'http://www.example.com';
    $ch =  curl_init($URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (stristr ($result, 'Domain')) {
        header('Location: '. $URL);
    }
    else{
        echo "No matches found";
    }
?>
```

**Old answer**

If you first want to show `ONLINE`, you would require something like a META-refresh.

Change the last line to:

```
echo (CONDITION HERE) '<html>
<head>
<title>Site online</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align:center; color:green">Online</div>" : "<div style='text-align:center; color:red'>Offline</div>
</body>
</html>';
```

If you don't need to first show `ONLINE` and just want to redirect, try:

```
if (stristr ($result, 'specificword')) {
  header('Location: http://www.example.com');
}
```

Also I suggest to use `mb_stristr` because it handles Unicode better.

Comment: Did you have any echo before the `header` call (because then it won't work)?

Comment: No, no echo, i jut replaced the echo line with the code u give me: `if (stristr ($result, 'specificword')) {
  header('Location: http://www.example.com');
}`

Comment: also, please add `http://` to the URL's. `svcss.t15.org/auth/homeaway/login/` is a valid URL, just not online, and it will probably fail to load.

Comment: Also in case of the `OFFLINE` part, add an else-branch and add `echo 'OFFLINE';` or something similiar.

Comment: I always put http:// when i declare an url so yes the http is present but still nothing happends, just blank page

Comment: Mobile right now. Will look into it within an hour.

Answer (score 0):

My updated code is as follows:

```
<?php
    $URL = 'http://www.example.com';
    $ch =  curl_init($URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (stristr ($result, 'Domain')) {
        header('Location: '. $URL);
    }
    else{
        echo "No matches found";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I edited your post and after it gets peer reviewed you have working code. Essentially, you are telling curl to open the url "$URL" (literally, not the contents of the variable $URL).

Comment: If you have working version, then you need to post it as an answer, but not as editing existing answer. Because your fix can be wrong or have different intent than answer's author.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov sorry, will do.

Comment: @jabbink and if i will have to check more than 1 url, let's say i have 3 urls, the script should check first url for the word and if it doesnt find it goes to check url 2 and so on, how the code should look?

Answer (score -1):

```
if something == true then
     header("location: myurl.com");
     exit;
end
```

Comment: This is not PHP and does not help in the problem where it does not detect the text on the page.